# py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o112.save

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running a pyspark job submit on a university server:

My configuration is :
`--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 150  --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 28g --driver-memory 28g`

My first few steps runs correctly :

```
df = spark.read.format('csv') \
                    .option('header',True) \
                    .option('multiLine', True) \
                    .load(data_file)
df.show()

udf_function = udf(stamp, StringType())
new_df = df.withColumn("column_a", udf_function(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))
new_df.show()
```

When I try to run the following commands separately, I get two very similar errors:

Command 1:

```
new_df.select("column_a").distinct().show(100)
```

Error:

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hadoop4/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249545/container_e01_1593105789029_2249545_02_000002/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hadoop4/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249545/container_e01_1593105789029_2249545_02_000002/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/hadoop4/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249545/container_e01_1593105789029_2249545_02_000002/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_stamp.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "python_stamp.py", line 82, in main
    new_df.select("planning_cluster_id").distinct().show(100)
  File "/hadoop4/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249545/container_e01_1593105789029_2249545_02_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 380, in show
```

Command 2:

```
new_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option("delimiter", ",").option("header", "true").save(save_path)
```

Error:

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hadoop1/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249417/container_e01_1593105789029_2249417_02_000002/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hadoop1/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249417/container_e01_1593105789029_2249417_02_000002/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/hadoop1/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249417/container_e01_1593105789029_2249417_02_000002/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_stamp.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "python_stamp.py", line 83, in main
    new_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option("delimiter", ",").option("header", "true").save(save_path)
  File "/hadoop1/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249417/container_e01_1593105789029_2249417_02_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 738, in save
  File "/hadoop1/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249417/container_e01_1593105789029_2249417_02_000002/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/hadoop1/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249417/container_e01_1593105789029_2249417_02_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/hadoop1/yarn/nm/usercache/apps/appcache/application_1593105789029_2249417/container_e01_1593105789029_2249417_02_000002/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 336, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o112.save
```

Does anyone know the reason behind it? I'm pretty confident that it's not because of any memory error, as the previous steps which show the table, load the table all are running correctly.

**Additional information:** When I run all of these commands on pyspark shell, they run perfectly well.

Comment: `Answer from Java side is empty` means the JVM has crashed

Comment: Do you about any possible remedy? Am I running out-of-memory?